# Convert Sturmey-Archer AW hub to AWC

Tags: internally-geared-hub, conversion, coaster

I have a 1972 Schwinn Breeze with a Sturmey Archer AW 3-speed hub (no coaster brake).  I would like to replace the internals of the AW hub with the internals of an AWC hub (which has a coaster brake).

Is this conversion possible without replacing the outer casing of the AW hub?  Not sure if the two hubs have interchangeable internals.

Comment: I'm guessing not - but if you're mechanically inclined you could open both, and compare?  Or even dry-fit the guts of the coaster-hub into the other shell?  The safest answer would be to relace the rim onto the coaster-hub.  Do please let us know what you find out.

Comment: Theres more than one AW and AWC hub. You can look at the parts diagrams [here](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/sturmey-archer_3-spd.html) for the AW and AWC you have and compare them, and maybe see if its doable.

Comment: I don't have access to an AWC, and was researching the feasibility before buying one.  I think, since one spoke is already loose on the AW hub, purchasing an AWC and re-spoking completely wouldn't be too crazy.  We'll see once it arrives!  Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My AWC hub was incompatible with AW hubs.
I find re-spoking much easier than working inside 3-speed hubs.
I left those 3-speed bikes behind at a beach house, but based on memory:
- AWC internals are removed from the coaster brake side, while
- AW internals are removed from the sprocket side.

3-speed hubs that I disassembled seemed beyond repair,
but to help reach your own conclusions about relative difficulty,
this video seems representative:
 [Clean/Lube Sturmey-Archer 3-Speed Hub - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNxwMwzS3Jo)

Comment: Welcome to SE - that's a useful data point, but its a very short answer.  Are you able to expand your answer with more information?

Comment: Thanks, the difference in how the internals are removed makes me confident that I don't want to attempt this :)